# Why my new Admob units don't get any ads?

Tags: android, error-handling, admob

All my new apps get "ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL" error and get "I/Ads: No fill from the ad server." and "W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3" errors in the Logcat.
My old apps still getting ads (from the same AdMob account), test ads are working well. 
I tried to install the app on another device and I got the same problem also created new ad units, tried different version of Android Studio but there was no hope and the weird thing is that when I create new APK files from the old projects they get the same error however the old APK files getting ads normally (Both of them uses the same ad unit id, AdMob account and same app id). I have been searching for a solution for a week, I tried everything and got the same error. everything looks normal but I don't know why I get this error, so please help me. I was working on a project and I am done but I can't get ads any more.
PLEASE HELP ME. and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem for admob ads .i added test id then also not showing ads on device. it's disable for 3-4 week after publishing live.
because there is only one download so.when you have 5+ installed device from store then your automatically showing on app.
if your admob ads are not showing on app don't worry it's will enable after few days.

Comment: I didn't upload it on play store , but i have test ads working and ads from the same id working on another app and it is not in play store